# Stripe Admin Payment Received Wordpress E-mail Content

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I want to edit the content of the payment received e-mails from Stripe in a WordPress build. Currently getting this:

*Dear Admin,*

*You have received payment for the following items:*

*XXX XXX XXX XXX*

*Order Summary*

*etc.*

I want to be able to include the username and e-mail of the customer in the e-mail. No option that I can see in the Stripe dashboard or anything to edit in the plugin core files

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's own emails do not have such customization options.

What you'd need to do is use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to catch [`charge.succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-charge.succeeded) events. The [event object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object) will include a [charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object) in its [`data.object`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object-data-object) attribute. If the charge was created with a customer, you will be able to [retrieve the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_customer) using the charge's [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-customer) attribute.

You can then use all this information to build and send an email to yourself.

Even though the usecase is not exactly the same, the following recipe might be very helpful to set up such a system: https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/sending-emails-for-failed-payments